# Asp.net suddenly cannot access files on file system

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our ASP.Net application randomly cannot access files in filesystem.

The files are accessed by native code fopen(filePath, "r")

Once this happens, only by recycling this troubled application pool everything is back to normal.

Running procmon did not reveal anything useful, and the static files were not locked at all, other application pool can access the static files.

Any thoughts of how to debug this ?

- ASP.NET 4.5
- .NET framework 4.5
- Windows Server 2016

The C code that fails on fopen()

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/branch-7-0/mapfile.c#L6739

Comment: There's 7,000 lines of code in that link, and three `fopens`. Please try a little harder to narrow down your problem. What's the exact error, and what line does it fail on?

Comment: it was line 6739 (as per the url fragment #L6739), took a while for github to load that file (10s using my connection).