# Diagnosing random but persistent "ASP.NET application initialization failed." error in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Since a couple of weeks we are encountering the 500 error  "ASP.NET application initialization failed." every few days in one of our many MVC asp.net applications. The error seems to randomly strike a different app and a different (load balanced) server each time. Once the error strikes the app pool consistently returns the same error until it is recycled. Then everything is ok again.

No error information is returned by the application (I have set CustomErrors off) and there is nothing relevant in the event viewer.

I have enabled failed request logging and have viewed traces for the given requests. The error consistently occurs in the following steps:

```
NOTIFY_MODULE_START 
    ModuleName ScriptModule-4.0 
    Notification AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
    fIsPostNotification false 

SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION 
    ErrorDescription ASP.NET application initialization failed.
```

Each failed request is more or less the same, except that the very first failed request has four extra informational steps which occur a few steps before the `AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST`. Each of these extra steps has the label `VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED`, with the names `FormsAuthentication`, `RoleManager`, `AnonymousIdentification`, and `UrlMappingsModule`.

One more interesting observation: in a "normal" failed request, that occurs due to an exception in the app code I see an event with the `AspNetStart` label BEFORE the `AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST` event. This event is missing in the request to the app when it is in the error state.

I don't know what I can do to further investigate this issue. Once it occurs it is easy to reproduce, but the lack of informative logging means I can't make any progress. Anybody any ideas?

Comment: our issue is somewhat related, random and can only be fixed by recycling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261270/asp-net-suddenly-cannot-access-files-on-file-system

Comment: what windows server are u using?

Comment: We are on server 2012, iis 8

Comment: We used add / remove windows features to remove the asp.net 4.7 support from iis and then reinstalled this feature. That made the random errors go away.